# Calculating effective percentage

Tags: percentages, ratio

I'm a middleman buying products on behalf of *my* clients. The `client` pays me `x` and I buy the product from `seller` for 25% of what the client pays me (for simplicity, I keep the remaining 75% of `x`). Sometimes, for reasons unrelated to my question, I need to buy from the seller at 60% (such that my profits are now 40% for this one purchase).

I'm trying to generalize a formula that tells me my effective margin. That is, if `x%` of the time I buy for `m%` of what I got from the client, and `y%` of the time I buy for `n%`, how do I compute what percentage of my income (what I got from the client) I spent (bought from sellers)?

**Edit**

To simplify, let's make the assumption that I always get paid the same amount by all clients (say, $100 always).

**Example**

Four transactions:

```
1. Received => $100; Bought => $25 (25%)
2. Received => $100; Bought => $25 (25%)
3. Received => $100; Bought => $25 (25%)
4. Received => $100; Bought => $45 (45%)
```

So 75% of the time, I bought at 25%. 25% of the time, I bought at 45%. My "effective percentage" was 0.3 (`(25*3+45)/400`).

Is there a generalized way to get my effective percentage (and is there a more precise term to describe what I'm trying to compute)?

Comment: You have to add up what you got from the client and what you paid the seller.  You can't do it just with the percentages unless the price to the client is the same for all items.  It could be that the low margin is on the most expensive items, in which case it will dominate.  It could be the other way around.